# Is there a Stack Exchange site for "how should I do..." questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I often have a lot of possible ideas on what my end result of code/program should be, but I want to know the best, or most logical solution in order to get to that, whether I know how to do it or not. Too often I think of something that I want to do, get stumped on it, then implement a certain way, only to find out after hours, or even hundreds of hours of work, when searching for a specific problem, that I find a better solution someplace. Since I'd already invested so much time, it's not always worthwhile to do a complete re-write.

So, does Stack Exchange offer any site like this where my "how should I do..." questions won't get closed immediately?

Comment: Yes. http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: "How should I do X" type of questions in most cases won't have a good ending. This is mainly because people don't share the same opinion as to how a problem should to be solved most of the time. Moreover, why you would want to trust someones opinion ? Do your own research and decide on your own what you believe solves the problem the best. This gives you the opportunity to grow as a developer as well instead of just coding what you have been told.

Comment: code review site says "Questions must contain working code for us to review it here", so that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more (or point to examples) about your questions? Programmers.SE _might_ be the more suitable site, especially if your questions are focused enough, but without a bit more information I can't be sure.

Comment: @coolmine that's understandable, but it seems that after googling my scenario for over a week now that I've already visited every site that comes up in my search results...gets frustrating, and alot of wasted time.

Comment: @Yannis current example: I'm working on an ELO rating system, but the number of games a player will have will only range from 10 to 40 for an entire season. Very hard to let the ratings "even out" with such few games across all players. Plus since my season is done, I know who SHOULD be ranked #1, 2, 3, etc (or at least very close to that), and my results are way off in some cases, so I need to figure out how to modify, either by the k factor, or something else in the formula to try and even it out, etc

Comment: Also, keep in mind, that my current example is MUCH more straight-forward than my original how-to question...

Comment: @Yannis to expand on my current example, one "hack" option that I'm trying to do is to repeat the process of calculating the elo by repeating the cycle, but take the end result elo rating from the previous cycle and use that as the beginning of the next cycle. Then keep repeating until the max or avg deviation from the last cycles elo rating to the current cycles elo rating are not greater than x. This gets me a little closer, but I'm noticing my problem players that should be much higher/lower are never going to end up [closer] to where they should be.

Comment: I've posed my example question on programmers.se http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/234673/how-can-i-tweak-my-elo-rating-system

Comment: Good, I was about to ask you to do just that. Personally, I think it's on topic for Programmers (btw I'm a moderator there), let's see what the wider Programmers community thinks. Small thing: You could try giving the question a more descriptive title.

Comment: @Yannis thanks, I updated the question title...